# keep writing to file after network filesystem disconnects

Tags: nfs, rsync, network-share, synchronization, sshfs

I'm trying to transfer a huge growing logfile in a way that will survive network partitions between the client and server. If the network connection is lost, I cannot afford to retransmit the entire file because of gross network utilization restraints. I will only sync an ongoing compressed version as follows

```
tail -f logfile | xz -3 -c > syncThis.xz
```

I've found multiple options for conducting the transfer on a continuous basis.

The one that I can understand best is `rsync --append`. If the connection cuts out, rsync will fail, then I can rerun the command to *resume* the transfer.

Another option seems to be sshfs or nfs, with or without autofs. With one of these the command above would change to

```
tail -f logfile | xz -3 -c > /mountLoc/syncThis.xz
```

and there would be no need for `rsync`.

**The question is this**: With a networked filesystem, if I continue appending to a synchronized file and the network cuts out and then resumes, will only and all of the remaining appends of the file be automatically transferred, similar to what `rsync --append` would do?

If this is not the default, is there a setting to enable such a thing?

I suppose such a filesystem would have to keep track of the fact that only appends had occurred on the file in the interim.